# Neo4j browser key not found

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using 3.1.3 version of my neo4j.
I got a graph which contains 312 nodes and had circular relationships.
Now I am trying to query a path from A to B show in the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGeiI.png) .
I think the reason it keeps running is my graph was a circular style.So it's going to like an infinite loop.So I am trying to use all() and filter() to set the condition that there can be only one relationship between nodes show in the image2.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOZIZ.png) But it shows key not found:r.

I wonder what this exception means and how can I fix it. I will be very appriciate.

Comment: please share the queries you are running.

Comment: match(n:roadlevelinfo{pointname:'A'})-[r:GO_TO]->(n2:roadlevelinfo{pointname:B})
where all(n in nodes(p) where 1=length(filter(m in nodes(p) where m=n)))
return p

Comment: I just want to set  there can be only one relationship between each nodes  in the path

Comment: I am also facing this problem with the version 3.0.7. My query is as follows. MATCH path=(from:User {id: 'id1'})-[:FRIEND_OF*]-> (to:User {id: 'id2'})
WHERE ALL(n in nodes(path) where 1 = size(filter(m in nodes(path) where m=n))) 
RETURN path,reduce(distance = 0, r in relationships(path) | distance+r.weight) AS totalDistance
    ORDER BY totalDistance DESC
    LIMIT 1

It gives the error " key not found:   UNNAMED68 "

Comment: @LinBernie Were you able to resolve this problem?

Comment: I solve my problem by using another way which is APOC dijkstra algorithm.Plugin the APOC into Neo4j and use this command
`call apoc.algo.dijkstra(...)`  it can also find the  shortest weighted path
@ Hareendra Chamara Philips